# Restrict all robots except Googlebot and Yandexbot

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

I want to allow Googlebot access all my pages with crawl delay. Yandexbot access only `index.html`. Bingbot access `/tools` pages.
All other bots will not be accessed my pages.

Is this *robots.txt* suitable for this?

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Crawl-delay: 300

User-agent: Yandex
Allow: /index.html
Disallow: /

User-agent: bingbot
Allow: /tools
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this code in your case:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Crawl-delay: 300
Disallow: 

User-agent: Yandex
Allow: /index.html
Disallow: /

User-agent: bingbot
Allow: /tools
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Even if `Crawl-delay: 300` directive is not a standard, just add the `Disallow:` directive for Googlebot and your code is fine.

Just for your information, to give only access to a page or a directory, you need to place `Allow` directive before `Disallow: /`.

More information on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add sitemap directive and Host (for Google and Yandex) in file robots.txt.
Host allows websites with multiple mirrors to specify their preferred domain.

```
Sitemap: http://www.example/sitemap.xml
Host: example.com
```